# Magento customization xml structure changes

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento and what I am trying to produce is the following ( but I am unsure how to do this):

1. How would I add new columns to the order page
2. How could I integrate XML for sending order data to what ever the location is that I am sending it to.

I am unsure about the folder structure how to modify the files to produce the above.  Do I do it via the lib hooks or other?

Were do I place the xml feed document etc

Comment: Take a look at magento document in the post below. Read then ask :)

Comment: Agreed, please try some things, then come here to report your findings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Magento Knowledge Base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento/)

[Magento U In-Person Classes (FD: I teach a couple of them)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/course-schedule)

[Magento U Video](http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/on-demand/)